# Возведение в степень и mod

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Доброго дня, столкнулся с очень нестандартной проблемой. Возвожу число в степень, например, 3 в степень 605, в итоге получается 4,553644 × 10 в стеепени 288. Потом беру mod этого числа на другое число и в итоге получается маленькое число. Так вот можно ли как-то в цикле возводить число в степень и делать mod т.к. присвоить такое огромное число какой-то переменной не получается?

```
 buffer = pow(alf_numbers[i],e);
 key[i] = buffer % n;
```

в буфере получается 4,553644 × 10 в стеепени 288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вычисляем `a ^ b mod m`

```
int r = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < b; i++) {
  r = r * a;
  r = r % m;
}

cout << r << endl;
```

если степени большие, то можно пользоваться быстрым возведением в степень.

берем [готовый алгоритм возведения в степень](http://kvodo.ru/byistroe-vozvedenie-v-stepen.html), исправляем ошибки и доделываем под нужды

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//быстрое возведение в степень
int bpow(int x, int n, int m)
{
  int count=1;
  if (!n) return 1;
  while (n) {
    if (n%2==0) {
      n/=2;
      x*=x;
      x %= m;
    } else {
      n--;
      count*=x;
      count %=m;
    }
  }
  return count % m;
}
//главная функция
int main() {
  int x; int n; int m;
  cout<<"Основание > "; cin>>x;
  cout<<"Степень > "; cin>>n;
  cout<<"модуль > "; cin >> m;
  cout<<x<<"^"<<n << " % " << m <<"="<<bpow(x, n, m);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KoVadim можно только пояснить ТС, что возведение в степень в общем случае -- это экспонента произведения на логарифм? И, соответственно, вычисления сугубо приближённые, после их приведения к целому результат вполне может удивить.

Comment: А не имеет значения, логарифм там или просто циклом. Здесь проблема в том, что количество разрядов сильно ограничено.

Comment: @KoVadim не понял. Возведение целого числа в целую степень с использованием логарифма и экспонененты -- это уже совсем отдельная песня, которая и даёт странный для новичка результат.

Comment: для новичка, который ещё в школе не прошел логарифмы. А так просто нужно сказать, что в большинстве языков программирование есть pow, который работает через экспоненту-логарифм и есть pow, который делает честные умножения.